# From a bunch of csv to json

Tags: python, json, csv

(I can't edit the title of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326723/add-an-array-to-a-dataframe and I think I don't have answers by the title.... I hope this can help)

I'm reading information from different .csv and I need to convert it to a .json

1.csv is:

```
field1: 1value1, field2: 1value2, field3: 1value3
```

The 2.csv have a lot of rows and I have to filter by 1value3

```
row1field1: 2value1, row1field2: 2value2, row1field3: 1value3, row1field4: 3.csv, 
row2field1: 2value4, row2field2: 2value5, row2field3: 1value3, row2field4: 4.csv,
```

3.csv is:

```
field1: 3value1, field2: 3value2
```

4.csv is:

```
field1: 4value1, field2: 4value2
```

I need my final json looks like:

```
{
    "field1": "1value1",
    "field2": "1value2",
    "field3": "1value3",
    "talbes": [
        {
            "row1field1": "2value1",
            "row1field2": "2value2",
            "row1field3": "1value3",
            "fieldsFromTable": [
                {
                    "field1": "3value1",
                    "field2": "3value2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "row2field1": "2value4",
            "row1field2": "2value5",
            "row1field3": "1value3",
            "fieldsFromTable": [
                {
                    "field1": "4value1",
                    "field2": "4value2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to works with dataFrame to convert after with dataFrame.to_json(), but I can't achieve to store an array of dataFrame into other dataframe... and really I don't know which is the better aprox to it.

Thanks

(I know it's a little messy this explanation... sorry)

Comment: what effort you have made so far?

Comment: Thansk Gahan, I say what I achive:

I can read a csv, and can convert to json

    table_url = '4.csv'

    # Build the string with data from table
    fields = pd.read_csv(table_url)

    # Convert the dataset to string
    string = fields.to_json(orient='records')

    # Writing the final json
    with open('survey_abbreviation' + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(string)